# How to get LaTeX Workshop showing equations previews as I move my cursor into inline math / math environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with a plugin called [LaTeX Workshop](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop) as my editor for LaTeX. The plugin has a very useful feature that it [shows previews of equations](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Hover#previewing-equations) as I move my *mouse* over over inline math, `\[`, `$$`, `\begin{align}`, and `\begin{...}` of other math environments.

My question is that if there is a easy way to get previews as I move my cursor into inline math / math environment using my *keyboard* only? I am looking for it because I really do not feel like getting my right hand leaving the keyboard to reach the mouse.

Comment: Looking at [this issues](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/809), I do not think there is a keybind for it.

Answer (score 3):

This has been my workaround:

`Ctrl+Shift+P` would open the command palette, search for LaTeX Workshop: Open Math Preview Panel (`@command:latex-workshop.openMathPreviewPanel`).

This would open a preview panel which you can put it below your code window so that you can get the preview synchronously as you move your cursor into math part using keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ctrl k + Ctrl i or see [Hover - LaTeX Workshop](https://github.com/jlelong/LaTeX-Workshop-wiki/blob/master/Hover.md)